# Access the GPS of the Android mobile in an web application, while browsing that app from that Android mobile

Tags: android, web-applications, gps

I want to develop a web application in ASP.NET and C# or in JavaScript that would access the GPS of the Android mobile, when the web application is browsed from that Android mobile.

Could that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use in-browser geolocation features. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_geolocation

Also you can user [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to forward some SDK methods to Javascript side of your web application (see http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and use `WebView.loadUrl('javascript:...');` to interact with WebApp side from SDK side.

Comment: can u provide me coding in that regards?

Comment: I can do that, but i need to understand more clearely what are you trying to do. Do you need to get a device's current location in a web-app, loaded into Android's browser (WebView) integrated to your Android app?

Comment: yeah thats what i have been looking for?

Comment: Then just add some JavaScript code to your WebApp. Exapmples can be found here: http://diveintohtml5.org/geolocation.html Note what user's premission will be requested while acuiring location.

Comment: The above link has changed location to http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html